# How to generate class diagram from xcdatamodel?

Tags: ios, xcode, class-diagram, xcode4.6, xcdatamodel

Is there any tool available which can generate a class diagram from existing xcdatamodel?

Comment: I think all these are done before project starts. However there is also a term called "Reverse-Engineering".

Comment: yes you are right. I am trying to reverse engineer a project. But how to generate the class diagram from an existing data model..there must be a way right.

Comment: If you switch the editor style to graph you will see Class Diagram.

Comment: You mean a _compiled_ xcdatamodel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCode provides a bit similar what you want...

here's the screen shot of that:
[image]